# How to get images to have text under the picture on desktop but to the right of the picture on mobile with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to bootstrap and was just wondering if there was a way to have basic pictures with captions that change position when on a smaller display. When on desktop I want the caption to display under the image but when on mobile I want the image to appear with the caption to the right of it.

Desktop:
[image: desktop]

Moblie:
[image: mobile]

Whenever I tweak the code, it seems to choose one or the other and either has text always under the image or always to the right of it.
Thanks a bunch!
Also is there a way to keep the footer at the bottom of my view but scrolls with the page?

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap Grid system to achieve this.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Following snippet will help you:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-1">
     <div class="thumbnail">
       <img src="..." alt="...">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-1 caption">
    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) and [offsets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) to taste.
2. If you set the `display` property of the image to `block`, the image will push the text to the next line.
3. You can use the `text-align` property to center the contents of the block.

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/g73dtek2/

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Align all centered */
  .breakfast {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .breakfast a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  /* Push the text to the next line */
  .breakfast img {
    display: block;
  }
}

/* Decorations */
.breakfast {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.breakfast img {
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row breakfast">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="//placehold.it/150x150/c69/f9c/?text=Food" alt="">
        Food   
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="//placehold.it/150x150/9c6/cf9/?text=Drink" alt="">
        Drink
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```